# Spring 6 StrictHttpFirewall semicolon

Tags: spring, spring-boot, url

After migration to the new Spring Boot 3 (which uses Spring 6), I am facing an issue with semicolons in URL. By default, this should not be allowed, which after debugging was proven to be correct. **StrictHttpFirewall** object throws the
`org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String ";"`

as it should. But this exception ends up in some **ObservationMarkingRequestRejectedHandler** where it is somehow handled, but not re-thrown.

Before migration, semicolons (and other special characters) were returning status code 400, but now when the exception is lost somewhere in the process, the status code is 200, which is wrong.

Anybody else facing this issue?